# Where the CREATE DATABASE statement is generated in Entity Framework Code First with Migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I need to configure the database created by Entity Framework Code First MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion class.

Is it possible to influence the database files parameters like size or maxsize? What interests me in particular, is there a way to add database files?

I assume I need to find the moment where the Entity Framework generates the CREATE DATABASE statement and influence it a bit. As far as I understand, the SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator class is too late because the database already exists at this point.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: According to comment this doesn't work:* 
<strike>You can just add code based migration using `Add-Migration` command and modify its `Up` method to execute `Sql("ALTER DATABASE ...")` and do what ever you want with your database.</strike>

Database is created through `DbProviderServices` - that is a bridging component between EF and specific database server. `ObjectContext` exposes operations for creating database and generating database creation script. `DbMigrator` use database creation operation when you execute `Update`. It checks that if Database exists and if not it uses `ObjectContext.CreateDatabase`. So if you want to change the process of creating the database you need to implement your own implementation of the migrator to change the way how `Update` method generates the database (maybe you just need a decorator which will create a database prior to executing `DbMigrator.Update` operation).

Comment: Can I really alter the database so late? (In Up function of the migration class). From quick test I got the "_ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction_" exception...

Comment: I didn't test it but I hoped it should work. So the second described solution is probably the only way to do that but you will have to use some initializer which will invoke your migrator instead of a default one.

Comment: As far as I understand, rewriting the migration mechanism leaves me without the default migration mechanism, as it would require inheriting the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` class where the important function `InitializeDatabase` does not seem to be very inheritance-friendly. As a current workaround I resort to creating the empty database from the outside script and letting the migration fill it with tables and relations.