# Upate-Database -script does not generate sql statement for creating database

Tags: entity-framework

When trying to create initial migration script using  "Update-Database -Script"
the output script does not contain sql statement for creating the database as specified in the connection string. 
Is it by design, or is there a way to make it generate database creation statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 'by design', if you need to modify database properties before doing any other work, you should do that with a script first.

[Where the CREATE DATABASE statement is generated in Entity Framework Code First with Migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328038/where-the-create-database-statement-is-generated-in-entity-framework-code-first)